# How can I get a list of User with their ID (list)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am trying to find out how to get a user list via their id in tabular form (array).

I've tried this :

```
let result = message.guild.members.get(id_list)
```

But it doesn't work ...

id list :

```
var id_list = [ '223515154229231616',
  '447425491041910807',
  '479932358422691840',
  '464536970417143828',
  '299429099611357185',
  '332868897646837762',
  '198346639843262464',
  '266078466972057600',
  '334270225895653379',
  '198884536363253761',
  '216595784286601216',
  '358993909269135371',
  '248894149162565647',
  '396681438688182284',
  '349270173011804171',
  '358319021726236672',
  '216136890963853313',
  '282994966014459915',
  '298171616968572930',
  '257809919036751872',
  '239365876846034944',
  '502162147942596609',
  '449391921840914444',
  '473229490584158208' ]
```

Comment: Can you explain in more detail? Where is `id_list` from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will not work as it is for one ID at a time, not an array of them. You would need to iterate over the IDs in the array, I suggest using a for loop for this, using `id_list.length` as one of the parameters. For example:

```
for(var i = 0; i <= id_list.length; i++) {
   //make the request to get the member information
}
```

Also, just to make sure, you might be better off using `client.users.get('id');` because if the user sends a direct message, there is no `guild` property so an error will be thrown.

Comment: You can't just place your existing code in there, you need to use the for loop. I suggest you do some research about how for loops work: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for that should help you as you'll need to use `i` to get the ID from the array.

Answer (score 1):

The following should do the trick

```js
let result = id_list.map(id => client.users.get(id));
```

Basically, you loop through all the ids you have using `.map()` and fetch the user associated.

You may want to remove all the undefined results (when your bot *"does not know"* the user linked to a specific id), in that case you need to add the following after the previous piece of code :

```js
result = result.filter(r => r !== undefined);
```

Check both the documentation of [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) for more information

Comment: I can't because, the ids are from a Data Base

Comment: @Antonin_04 oh sorry for the misunderstanding, I edited my answer to fit your needs

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
 let result = id_list.map(id => client.users.get(id).tag)
```

That should give back an array with like

```js
['User#0000',
'NextUser#4821'
]
```